# How to use XDocument.Load to load cached pages from IIS sever

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, url, caching, linq-to-xml

We have a WPF application which is requesting RSS feeds through url from our MVC website using  **XDocument.Load()** function. Although in the MVC web application we are caching the RSS page for 15 minutes, the wpf application is still requesting a new rss page every time ignoring the cache in the server. How do we use the cached pages in our WPF application?

Here is the code:

```
Path.Combine((Directory.GetParent(App.DisplayFilePath)).Name, "RSS.xml");

XDocument doc;

doc = XDocument.Load(this.FeedUri.AbsoluteUri);
doc.Save(cacheXmlFile);

doc = XDocument.Load(cacheXmlFile);

var feedItems = from feed in doc.Descendants("item");
```

Here is the code in the Server side mvc application:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 900, VaryByParam = "*")]
public RssActionResult GetBranches(int gid = -1, string gname = "", int t = -1,
                                   int tgap = 0)
{            
    var feedItems = new List<feedItem>();
    var branches = db.usp_GetBranch(gid, gname, t, tgap).ToList();
    feed.Items = feedItems;
    return new RssActionResult() { Feed = feed };
}
```

The WPF application is requesting this action through url in the server side. Is the OutputCache attribute OK?

Comment: How are you declaring the cache value? Are you declaring a client-side cache value or a server-side one?

Comment: I have declared a server-side cache in our mvc application, it caches the thing if visit it by browser, but not by WPF app. I did not declare cache in WPF application. How do I do so?Thanks!

Comment: The server side cache means that your server will serve the data from the cache when a client requests it. This means that the client will still request it. What you need to do is to specify a value for the client-side cache when transmitting the data.

Comment: Thanks, I have posted server side code. How do I configure the output attribute? Thanks.

Comment: Try specifying the `Location` property of the `OutputCache` attribute: `Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any` or `Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to add the specified location to the output cache to see if it works.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the communication between wpf application and asp.net web application. Can wpf client apps share the cache in the IIS server side? Any one knows?